# Ultrafilter Lemma and Dimension Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, axiom-of-choice

Reading on Wikipedia I find out that (the uniqueness in) the Dimension Theorem for arbitrary Vector Spaces can be proved using just the Ultrafilter Lemma (a strictly weaker version of Axiom of Choice). Is it hard to prove using just Ultrafilter lemma? Is there any references I could see?

Comment: To your first question, http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-03/S0002-9939-1966-0194340-1/S0002-9939-1966-0194340-1.pdf is the reference you seek.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good answer to the first question!

Comment: Does that mean that my comment answers your question now?

Comment: Yes :) I will do some other more specific questions (since I have also answered by myself some of my previously ones).

Comment: Should I upgrade the comment to an answer?

Comment: I think it will be better.

Comment: I belive there's a mistake: the dimension theorem for arbitrary vector spaces is equivalent to the axioms of choice while, as you stated above, the ultrafilter lemma is not.

Comment: Well yes, I mean just the uniqueness condition.

Comment: @Giorgio: As I recall, and Wikipedia seems to agree, the dimension theorem simply states that any two bases have the same cardinality. It does not assert the existence of a basis.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, ok thanks. For me the dimension theorem was the one stating the existance of a basis... guess I was wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the proof in the paper:

> *James D. Halpern*, [**Bases in vector spaces and the axiom of choice**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=194340), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **17** (1966), 670--673.